# Alternate ways to charge trio tablet

Tags: tablet, charging

I recently acquired a [Trio:) STEALTH G5 10.1](http://www.triotablets.us/tablets/android-tablets/trio-stealth-g5-10-1/) tablet for free. The one problem that I can find is that the micro USB port is a little bashed in. There is no way to get the charger in. It also has an SD card slot and 3.5mm headphone jack. It seems to be a quite nice tablet, and I'd like to use it if I can.

**Is there any other way that I can charge this tablet?**

Comment: what do you mean another way? does the battery is integrated? your link Say's 404 not found.

Comment: @Seynal I mean might it be possible to charge through one of the other ports, or open it up an charge somehow?

Comment: I have a SmartPhone with integrated battery, the charger port is dead, What I did to charge it is to open it up the cover at the back by using a paper clip and remove the battery and charge it using a universal clip charger. I don't know if it will work on you.